# In Scala, how to work around TraversableLike.toIterator's inefficient intermediate Stream

Tags: scala, collections

(`Gen`)`TraversableOnce.toIterator` is overridden in `TraversableLike` as `toStream.iterator`, causing an intermediate stream to occur.

As a simple example, say I'm trying to implement a simple `izip` utility that always coerces its arguments to iterators before calling `zip` so as to yield an efficient iterator over both collections.

The following is inefficient (due to the intermediate Stream):

```
def izip[A,B](xs: TraversableOnce[A], ys: TraversableOnce[B]) =
  xs.toIterator zip ys.toIterator
```

and must be expanded to:

```
def izip[A,B](xs: Iterable[A], ys: Iterable[B]) =
  xs.iterator zip ys.iterator
def izip[A,B](xs: Iterator[A], ys: Iterable[B]) =
  xs zip ys.iterator
def izip[A,B](xs: Iterable[A], ys: Iterator[B]) =
  xs.iterator zip ys
def izip[A,B](xs: Iterator[A], ys: Iterator[B]) =
  xs zip ys
// .. and more needed to handle Traversables as well
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I think that traits guarantee only the existence of a given method, not its implementation. They can provide a *default* implementation, but subtype can override it.

So even if TraversableLike provides an implementation for `toIterator`, the actual implementation of the object you pass will be used.

If you have performance problems with standard collections, perhaps the real issue is elsewhere. If it's a custom collection, you should override `toIterator` with a sensible definition.

Comment: (1) Yes, I know that subtypes can override `.toIterator`. (2) I had already profiled the code and determined that the biggest bottleneck was from Stream. Using `.iterator` instead of `.toIterator` removed that bottleneck and resulted in a 180% speedup. This is what prompted my question. `.toIterator` is not being overridden, at least for iterators on even array-backed sequences.

Comment: Indeed, I had again a look at the collection source. Apparently if `.iterator` seems the optimized method, and `.toIterator` seems to be always backed by `TraversableLike` which the slow default implementation you described.